# How can I get the next page of friends using the Twitter API?

Tags: twitter, twitterizer

I am using the api twitterizer2 downloaded from
http://code.google.com/p/twitterizer/downloads/list
but when I try to get the friends of a user I get 100 friends but 
I can't get the next 100 friends through the NextPage function.
How can I handle this...?

```
 Twitterizer.TwitterUserCollection userFollowing = 
      Tw.TwitterUser.GetFriends(tokens,TwitterUrl);
 Twitterizer.TwitterUserCollection page2=userFollowing.NextPage;
```

When I get the next page it returns the same 100 users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paging is still being worked out in the beta. I'm planning on having it worked out before I release Beta 2.

Please send additional questions to our mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/twitterizer